# Version compatibility between google-api-client and google-api-services

Tags: java, versioning, google-api-java-client

There is a project which depends on `google-api-client` and `google-api-services-drive`.

`google-api-client` verion looks like this: `1.23.0`, and there is a changelog on github for this library.

`google-api-services-drive` version looks like this: `v3-rev105-1.23.0`, and there is no clear changelog.  There is a number of different `rev` suffixes for the same version number, like `v3-rev116-1.23.0`, `v3-rev135-1.23.0`, etc. It looks like it is built weekly with an increasing revision number.

The question is: How are client and services versions compatible? Is it safe to assume, that any service with version `v3-revXXX-1.23.0` is compatible with client `1.23.0` , and any api-service with version `v3-revYYYYMMDD-1.32.1` is compatible with api-client `1.32.1` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it may look like common semantic versioning part signals compatibility, that doesn't seem to be the case.

However, there is a simple way to find out which `google-api-client` version a particular `google-api-service` requires. The thing is, `google-api-service` has a dependency on `google-api-client`, which you can... right, you can find it in a POM-file!

Looking at POM-files of different services, there are cases when, for example, a service version is `v3-rev20210201-1.31.0` and it depends on a client version `1.31.1`, while `v3-rev20210612-1.31.0` depends on `1.31.5`
Or even worse: a service version `v3-rev20220508-1.32.1` depends on a client version `1.34.0`.

Comment: what a mess..., even the error message I got is laughable: `You are currently running with version 2.0.0 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version 1.23.0 of the Drive API library.`

Comment: I [reported this error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268844492) to Google.  I tried downgrading my api-client lib to "v1.35.2" in `build.gradle` but for some reason the build keeps using v2.2.0.

Comment: same for me for gmail api. `You are currently running with version 2.0.0 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.31.1 of google-api-client to run version 1.32.1 of the Gmail API library.`

Comment: FYI you can find a version 2.0.0 here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-androidpublisher/v3/2.0.0 - but to be blunt the whole process of setting this up is a mess

Comment: For those that got here from google like me, I was extremely confused cause mvn sorts by version I guess? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive So I thought latest version was `v3-rev197-1.25.0`.  If you CTRL+F 2023 you'll find the more up to date versions, which at this time is `v3-rev20230822-2.0.0`

Comment: @CeePlusPlus it looks like they switched the naming schema from revision number to revision date. Confusing indeed.

Answer (score 1):

To help someone else in need, I had the same problem accessing google sheets. My solution was use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
  <version>v4-rev20230815-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe the solution for this case is the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-androidpublisher</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev20230905-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev20220927-2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```